# Group by Week in Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to get a count of items within a 7-day period, while still being able to report the first date of said seven day period. The closest I've come so far is

```
WITH w (w, n)
AS 
(
    SELECT MIN(CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE)) 
                OVER(   
                        PARTITION BY DATEPART(WEEK, CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE)) 
                        ORDER BY DATEPART(WEEK, CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE))
                    )
            ,COUNT(*)
    FROM dbo.Tbl
    WHERE 
        CreatedDate >= CAST(DATEADD(MONTH,-6,GETDATE()) AS DATE)
    GROUP BY CAST(CreatedDate AS DATE)
)
SELECT w.w AS [Week of], SUM(w.n) AS [Items]
FROM w
GROUP BY w.w
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

But this unfortunately does not work for the first or last week of the year, and will not work if the date range includes more than one year.

Is there a way to group by a seven day period while still being able to get the first date in said period?

Comment: instead of using DATEPART, use a DATEDIFF of weeks from a start date. e.g. `PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(WEEK, myStartDate, CreatedDate)...` etc

Comment: @ZLK  This will only work when the `@@DATEFIRST` value of the server corresponds to the start of the 7 day period required for the analysis.

Comment: @iamdave indeed. it should be datediff(day...)/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to get your weeks based on your date value.  You will need to play around with the days added to get the right days of the week for your situation, but you will always be guaranteed the same start and end day.  In this case the week starts on Sunday and ends on Saturday:

```
declare @Date datetime

set @Date = '20160802'

select @Date - DATEPART(dw, @Date) + 1 as FirstDateOfWeek
      ,@Date + (7 - DATEPART(dw, @Date)) as LastDateOfWeek
```

For a fully bulletproof solution you could add in logic to check and use `@@DATEFIRST` and assign the adjustment values accordingly.

Once you have your week start value, you can use that in your `group by`:

```
select CreatedDate - DATEPART(dw, @Date) + 1 as FirstDateOfWeek
      ,count(*)
from tbl
group by CreatedDate - DATEPART(dw, @Date) + 1
order by FirstDayOfWeek
```